# Constructing a monad via type synonyms of a particular kind

Tags: lambda-calculus, category-theory

We can define a reader/environment monad on the simply-typed lambda calculus, using the following three equations, where $r$ is some fixed type, $\alpha$ is any type (I subscript some terms with their types), $\mathbb{M}$ is the proposed monadic type modality), $\eta$ is the *unit* of the monad and $\mu:\mathbb{M} \mathbb{M}\alpha → \mathbb{M}\alpha$ is the *join* of the monad:

$$\mathbb{M} \thinspace α = r → α  \hspace{1cm} ∀α$$
$$ \eta \, a_{\alpha} = \lambda c_{r}.\; a \hspace{2cm} ∀a_{\alpha}$$
$$\mu\,b_{\mathbb{M}\mathbb{M} \alpha} = λc_{r}.\; b_{\mathbb{M}\mathbb{M}\alpha}\, c\, c \hspace{1cm} ∀b_{\mathbb{M}\mathbb{M} \alpha} $$

Can we always construct a reader monad by type synonyms of the form $r = x$, for arbitrary function types $x$ (for example, where $x$ is $((\beta \to t) \to t$), for some type $\beta$?

Comment: Yes. You just did it. What is the question?